# Drop rows that contains the same value in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently working on a data frame like the one below:

| artist | week1 | week2 | week3 | week4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Drake | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| Muse | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Bruno Mars | 3 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| Imagine Dragons | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Justin Timberlake | 2 | 2 | NA | 1 |

What I want to do is to drop the rows that only contain "NA" values. The result should be something like this:

| artist | week1 | week2 | week3 | week4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Drake | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| Bruno Mars | 3 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| Justin Timberlake | 2 | 2 | NA | 1 |

I've tried using the pandas `drop()`  function but drops every row with at least one "NA" value. In that case, the row for Justin Timberlake would be dropped but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`df.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and set `how='all'` meaning If all values are `NA`, drop that row or column. then set the `subset` columns.

```py
df = df.dropna(how='all', subset=['week1', 'week2', 'week3', 'week4'])
print(df)
```

Or *Keep only the rows with at least 2 non-NA values.*

```
df = df.dropna(thresh=2)
print(df)
```

---

```
              artist  week1  week2  week3  week4
0              Drake    2.0    2.0    3.0    1.0
2         Bruno Mars    3.0    3.0    4.0    2.0
4  Justin Timberlake    2.0    2.0    NaN    1.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another question though. Is there another way to set the subset when the number of columns is too large to write the name of each one? For example, if I have 300 weeks columns.